# Problems with writing a code to import excel files into database with asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm having problems with importing Excel data into a database. I receive the following error:

> An OLE DB Provider was not specified in ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider = SQLOLEDB;'.

Here's my code:

```
using System;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadBtn.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUploadBtn.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadBtn.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls":
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }

    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1= excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();

        dtExcel.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3]
        {
            new DataColumn ("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn ("City",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn ("Age",typeof(int))
        });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1+ "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcel);
        }

        excel_con.Close();
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["costumizadoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.test";

                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Age", "Age");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcel);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="costumizadoConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Integrated Security=True; Provider=SQLNCLI10.1"
     providerName="System.Data.OleDb"  />
    <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
    <add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Error line:

```
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Excel03ConString` and `Excel07+ConString` connection strings are missing the `provider` attribute name. Change them to the following:

```xml
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
<add name="Excel07+ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
```

Comment: When I put the "provider" i get the following error: 
Unsupported keyword: 'provider'.  That's why I took out the "provider" Error line: using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))

Comment: The connection strings for [ACE](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/) and [JET](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/) connection strings both show that they require the `Provider` attribute name.

Comment: Lews I did that and I got a brand new error : 
"ConnectionString property not initialized" In this line:  excel_con.Open(); Don't know what it means to be honest

Comment: @PedroPereira What is the value of `conString` when you debug and put a breakpoint on the `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))` line?

Comment: I already fix that error, Now im getting another that is: "could not find installable isam" on line: excel_con.Open();